# Can I set a simple key-value pair using amp-state?

Tags: html, amp-html, express-handlebars

I am trying to set a simple {key: value} pair using amp-state. Currently in my code there I have to initialize on every set state for key - value pairs.

The project is using express-handlebar templates and AMP for state management in the templates. There is a default handlebar value for each key.

But when one value is changed I have to initialize all the amp state values. This leads to a lot of duplicate code that could be improved a lot by setting state an initial. But to refactor all amp state into a big object containing the key-value pairs will complicate my code quite a bit so i'd rather not use the exact examples you can find on amp documentation.

For example I would like to replace something like this:

```
tap:AMP.setState({
     lng: 'en',
     selectedVal: selectedVal || '{{baseVal}}',
     rate: rate || {{lookup currencyRates  baseCurrency}},
     symbol: symbol || '{{lookup symbols baseCurrency}}'
}),
```

with

```
tap:AMP.setState({
     lng: 'en', 
}),
```

In order to do this (and avoid errors) I would need to initialize all fields at the bottom of the page using `<amp-state>...</amp-state>` (and only changing the language in this case)

I tried to search for a solution, but I was not able. Does anyone know if there is a solution? If yes witch? If not, does anyone knows why?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my answer. Maybe it will help others too.

So even tough in the [amp bind](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/) documentation there are no examples with just a key-value pair, seems like on [this](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-bind/?referrer=ampbyexample.com&format=websites#initializing-state) page there is. 
The conclusion is you can load a simple key-value pair by just inserting a simple string inside the script tag (similar to this example they have on the second page):

```
<amp-state id="myText">
  <script type="application/json">
    "World"
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

I found it quite confusing because I was expecting that inside the script tag you should place a json object. But this seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

AMP.setState allows you to deep merge state objects:

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/?format=websites#deep-merge-with-amp.setstate()

I think you're missing initialisation of a state object which will allow you to populate state with your default values.

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/?format=websites#initializing-state-with-amp-state

You can do this either by a) rendering JSON directly into an `amp-state` component or b) by using the `src`
attribute to retrieve data from an endpoint.

**a) Server-rendered state**

```
<amp-state id="myStateObject">
<script type="application/json">
{
    "lng": "en",
    "selectedVal": "lookup baseVal",
    "rate": "lookup currencyRates baseCurrency",
    "symbol": "lookup symbols baseCurrency"
}
</script>
</amp-state>
```

OR

**b) Using the src attribute**

```
<amp-state id="myStateObject" src="/some/json/endpoint"></amp-state>
```

This gives you access to `myStateObject` which you can then use to merge an object literal with your current state.

```
<button
    on="tap:AMP.setState({
        myStateObject: {
            selectedVal: 'newSelectedVal'
        }
    })"
>
    Click me
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I kind of understand that. I read the amp documentation. But my problem is that the state was not created by me and we have several key-value pairs witch are not initialized. Instead the handlebar value is printed initially and the state is initialized with the help of AMP.SetState(). But when you initialize one value, you need to set all the key-value pairs.

Comment: Now I know this is not correct but it was like this when I got on the project and it would require a lot of work to change the state into nested objects (as I pointed out right now we just have, for example, lng state witch is not an object, but a string, containing the current language value). So should I understand that this is not possible and is generally a bad practice with amp-state?